# Проблема с определением скрипта

Tags: requirejs

У меня не получается получить данные с API другого сайта. Для этого я использую следующий скрипт:

```
<script data-main="https://......." src="https://......./require.min.js"></script>
```

Но, он не выполняется. Firebug показывает следующую ошибку: “Mismatched anonymous define() module …”. Я предполагаю это из-за того, что они используют RequireJS и мне нужно каким-то образом не анонимно сделать вызов.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на сайт. В вопросах не приветствуются различные "лирические отступления" (в том числе приветствия). Желательно иметь в тексте вопроса побольше технических подробностей. В данном случае было бы полезно понимать что за API и видеть ваш код. Firebug при возникновении ошибки указывает на номе строки с ошибкой. Это тоже неплохо бы знать.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего дело в ключе, его у вас нет, а значит данные получить не сможете

Comment: Думаю нет, у меня есть и id и ключ авторизации

Comment: Ну тогда защищенное соединение в нем может быть причина